# Which Azure Blob client library to use? Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common or WindowsAzure.Storage?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage

Which client library is the correct one to use when working with .NET framework 4.7.1?

[Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common/) or 
[WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **WinowsAzure.Storage**.

```
Install-Package WindowsAzure.Storage
```

Within the public [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Common/README.md), they advise against referencing Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common directly:

> The Microsoft Azure Storage Common SDK for .NET is referenced by Azure
>   Storage Blob/Queue/File SDKs and Azure CosmosDB Table SDK and should
>   not be referenced directly by your application

Further reading: [Azure Storage APIs for .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/storage?view=azure-dotnet)

Comment: Thank you very much. Are there any history/information regarding "Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common" library available besides the official link? When should it be used or why it even exists?